# Looping through two lists in parallel

Tags: sas

I have the following values

```
Time  Value
3      0.03

6      0.04

9      0.05

12      0.06
```

As you can see, they move at steps of three and one respectively.
If I want to apply the following formula for each of them

```
X=sum(X,2/value)
```

What should I do?

I have tried as follows:

```
data want;
array my_array{0-10} $ _temporary_;
X=0;
Do i=1 to 5;
My_array(i)=sum(x,2/value)*i;
X= =sum(x,2/value)*i;
End;
Total=X;
Run;
```

However I am not looping through value, only through time (i goes from 1 to 4).
I would like to calculate for each time X applying the formula above, in order to have one column extra in the table above, then get the sum of these values.

In the example provided by Kermit in the answer below, the expected output (values under x should satisfy the formula mentioned above) would be the following:

```
time  value x  sum_x
 3    0.03 200 
 6    0.04 300 
 9    0.05 360 
 12   0.06 400
```

Comment: Edit your question to show us your expected output. You don't set any table in your data step.

Comment: Hi Kermit. Time is meant in the code as number of periods. so it is just i in the loop. You can think as quarterly base.: do i to (m-1) where m is 12/3. I fixed the question as I added one time step not necessary. It would be also fine to see how a loop through two lists works, considering a formula that can take as parameters both (so time and value). I am interested in the output through time and in the final (sum). It would be great if the formula could be something cumulative. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would like to generate the table (no set table) by running the two loops through time, where 3 correspond to 1, 6 to 2 and so on. So the do loop should include four time steps (12/3)

Comment: So you would end up with 16 records right? one for each value and time?

Comment: Yes, I would have at the end 4 columns, for a total of 16 records

Comment: Where did the values 200, 300 etc come from?  Are they inputs?  Then show the expected output.  If they are the outputs then explain how you calculated them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, time would be set on a quarterly basis and you would like to get the sum of X for each time. Next time, consider giving the expected output in your question.

```
data stage1;
    do time=3 to 12 by 3;
        do value = 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06;
            x=(2/value)*time;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

proc sort data=stage1;
    by time value;
run;

data want;
    do _n_=1 by 1 until(last.time);
        set stage1;
        by time;
        sum_x=sum(sum_x, x);
        output;
    end;
run;
```

```
time  value x  sum_x
 3    0.03 200  200
 3    0.04 150  350
 3    0.05 120  470
 3    0.06 100  570
 6    0.03 400  400
 6    0.04 300  700
 6    0.05 240  940
 6    0.06 200  1140
 9    0.03 600  600
 9    0.04 450  1050
 9    0.05 360  1410
 9    0.06 300  1710
 12   0.03 800  800
 12   0.04 600  1400
 12   0.05 480  1880
 12   0.06 400  2280
```

---

**EDIT after comments**

Why would you use a do loop? Just perform element-wise multiplication within a table.

```
data want;
    set have;
    x=(2/value)*time;
    retain sum_x 0;
    sum_x=sum(sum_x, x);
    output;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Kermit, yes you understood correctly.  Thanks. In your code, the set table is that one that I provided, right? Is there any way to loop without using a set table, as I need to calculate values to be incremented? I mean, starting from 0.03 as value, just increment by 0.01 to create a table from scratch as your, considering quarterly

Comment: @LdM Yes it is. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry Kermit! One point. Since the two loops should run in parallel, i should get one value for each time: 3 should have only assigned value 0.03; 6 only value 0.04,… so not multiple values. My poor explaining. There will be 16 records, but across all the columns

Comment: Added the expected output. Sorry again for my poor explaining. A possible solution would be to initialise the value and after the first time in the loop to increment it. However, I am wondering if there is something that I could do using two loops in parallel, where the increment is done at the same time for both

Answer (score 2):

Your expected results do not seem to match your explanation of the formula. You could use two arrays to allow you to pair the TIME and VALUE amounts.

```
data want;
  array t [4] _temporary_ (3 6 9 12);
  array v [4] _temporary_ (0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06);
  do index=1 to dim(t);
    time=t[index];
    value=v[index];
    x=sum(x,2/value)*index;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    index    time    value       x

 1       1        3      0.03      66.67
 2       2        6      0.04     233.33
 3       3        9      0.05     820.00
 4       4       12      0.06    3413.33
```